# Music ambience of an antagonist appearing in a cutscene or approaches a dark, low bass music will play

Tags: identify-this-genre, soundtrack, identify-this-sample, identify-this-instrument

I notice this in shows/movies like Invincible, Star Wars, and The Good Place on Netflix that, **villainy low bass orchestra ambient music** will begin once a villain or any antagonist enters the scene.

I've looked for music in the genre it could find, but I haven't been able to locate anything that sounds like it.

If you have questions, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Music Fans! Unfortunately this looks like an (off-topic) identification question without being specific on what to identify (needs details or clarity). For background see https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: I don't think it's a genre as much as inspired by the iconic Darth Vader "Imperial March" theme from Star Wars. So I guess... march music? Lots of heavy metal would be inspired by march music too, if that's your thing. Rammstein in the first that springs to mind (_Links 2 3 4_ or _Du Hast_ are good examples), as well as lots of Power Metal.